# unable to add UINavigationController to ModalViewController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am using a UIModalViewController in my project where I am unable to add a UINavigationBar  at the top. I am also using other UIModalViewControllers in my project where I am successful with adding UINavigationBar. The only difference between the unabled UIModalViewController and the others is, it is linked to several other ViewControllers (all using a modal "push" to it) where the other ModalViewControllers are just linked to 1 other ViewController.

I am using the following code when I am trying to add a UINavigationController to it:

```
ShowTaskViewController *detailViewController = [[ShowTaskViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES  completion:nil];
[navController release];
[detailViewController release];
```

But no bar gets added. I am not getting any errors or anything. Any Idea what may have happened here ?

Comment: There is no such class as `UIModalViewController`.

Comment: Sorry, but what I am mean is: I am using a "modal push" to the ViewController and I therefor call it UIModalViewController. Because a normal push is totally different when it comes to UINavigationController settings....

Comment: The above code looks fine. Try `[self presentModalViewController:...` instead of `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:...`